# Correct Join Query for SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I currently have the following Query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Cars c
        INNER JOIN tbl_Car_Parts cp ON c.Id = cp.Id
        INNER JOIN tbl_Car_Factory cf ON cp.Id = cf.Id
```

However I have now realised that there are some Ids which are in the Cars Table which are then not in the Car Parts table so these are being omitted from my results while I want them included.  I tried changing my INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN but it made no difference in the result set I am returned?

Comment: Are those all the right fields, or should you maybe be looking at CarId and PartId in the Parts and Factory tables respectively?

Comment: Did you do the same for car factory? Because that would omit them as well (as an inner join)

Comment: Which DBMS?  Did you mean to join on the same ID in all tables??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in **both** of the joins.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Cars c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Car_Parts cp ON c.Id = cp.Id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_Car_Factory cf ON cp.Id = cf.Id
```

Otherwise the second `INNER JOIN` will invalidate your first `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for those records that does not have ID (does not join) in the `tbl_Car_Parts` table.

After a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you may be only use again `INNER JOIN` if the table you are joining is not related with the previous ones that are joined using the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Hi - this was want I needed - Thanks Rafa - will mark as accepted when I can - I had only done the LEFT OUTER on my first JOIN

Comment: You are welcome @KOL. I guessed it as soon as I saw your query because it used to happen to me as well, before I understand the above text I have wrote after the query.

Comment: And be aware that if you need to filter on one of the columns in those two tables it needs to be in the join not the where clasue or you will change it back to an implict inner join.

Comment: @HLGEM: very good appreciation because I think it is a very common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN should have definitely solved your problem, Not sure why it didnt work. 
Just to be safe I used Left join on both the tables...

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Cars c
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Car_Parts cp ON c.Id = cp.Id
        LEFT JOIN tbl_Car_Factory cf ON cp.Id = cf.Id
```